# How to display hours in JQuery datapicker

Tags: javascript, css

I want to use simple JQuery datapicker but not only to select the date. I want to add hours to the date format but I also want to preserver the classic vie of the calendar. I just want to add hours as extra functionality to define precisely the time. Is this possible?

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        //For calendar
                        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                            inline: true,
                            showWeek: true,
                            firstDay: 1,
                            dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss',
                        });                            
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

you can try the above plugin with the combination of datepicker

you can even use the default `$('.datepicker').datetimepicker();`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI's datepicker picks dates, not times. You can add a distinct field for the hours, e.g. a select field.